# onBackPressed() override

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

This is the structure of my application:

Activity A is a `ListViewActivity` with a button to start B activity.

In the B activity after completing a form is there a button to start the C activity.

The C activity save the setting and create a new record to show in A activity. The Button save in C activity launch the A activity.

If the user follow this procedure more than once when he press the back button from the A activity return on the B(without passing through the C because when I started it I set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`) and the second time he press back return to A again, and this repeats number of time equal to the number of created records.

Close the app with back button became a long process.

I would like the `onBackPressed` from the A activity always close the app.

English is not my language, I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start your activity A like below

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(current_activity_context, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method  finish() will do that. 
Something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Activity B.class);
        Activity A.this.startActivity(intent);

        finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override the OnBackPressed method

```
@Override
public void OnBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();//Optional
 }
```

Hope it helps.